# Python programming (python 2.7.10) : IF loop

Tags: python-2.7, loops, if-statement

I have done a program in Python 2.7.10 to find the character at a given position. However there seems to be a problem with the IF loop...

```
n= raw_input() #input string
print(n)
t= raw_input() #position of the character in the string to be retrieved
for i in range(0,10):
  if i == t;
    print(n[i-1])
```

Output:

```
 hey
hey
 1
```

I have executed this program in repl.it. During the iteration the IF loop checks whether the value i takes the value of character 't' instead of the varaible t where the position of the character to be obtained is stored..any ideas on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use variable t as an int. raw_input will return a string. You'll have to convert it to int. try this

```
n= raw_input() #input string
print(n)
t= raw_input() #position of the character in the string to be retrieved
for i in range(0,10):
  if i == int(t):
    print(n[i-1])
```

I don't know what you are trying to do, but the best way you can get the character from input position is,

```
n= raw_input() #input string
print(n)
t= int(raw_input())
print(n[t-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop if your requirement is as you mentioned in your question:

```
n= raw_input("Enter a string:") #input string
print("You entered: {}".format(n))
t= int(raw_input("Enter a positionf of the character to be retrieved:")) #position of the character in the string to be retrieved
if t < 1 or t > len(n):
    print ("Not found.")
else:
    print ("You asked for: {} at index {}".format(n[t-1], t))
```